# Why this layout has scrollbars in IE only?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have a layout that works fine in Chrome, but the main content area is giving scrollbars when it should be a 100%. Can this be corrected in IE?

The main content area is black in this layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/mp8nr/34/

Comment: did you add html5 supporting jquery for ie ? try this overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the scrollbars or make them show/hide automatically:

**CSS**:

```
html, body {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

That will sort your problem.

Comment: I had to use hidden. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use `#wrap {height:300px;}` in pixel or `#wrap {height:50%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you shouldn't need to just turn scroll bars off -

poss check use of the margins in the CSS.